# Consumo vs consumismo vs consumerismo

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, sustantivos

¿Cuándo se usa cada palabra? Imagino que las diferencias son pequeñas (pero creo que, pero todavía quiero saber).

Especialmente al decir "too much consumption / over-consumerism", ¿cuál se usaría? (Por ejemplo, ¿se diría "el **consumo** excesivo" o "el **consumismo** excesivo" o "el **consumerismo** excesivo"?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly speaking, Spanish *[consumismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AT2HJjb)* means the same as English *consumerism*, and Spanish *consumo* means the same as English *consumption* (in the economic sense of "acquiring goods and services").

Spanish *[consumerismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumerismo)* is a neologism that has nothing to do with English *consumerism*. According to the Spanish Wikipedia:

> El término **consumerismo** hace referencia a la soberanía del consumidor
>   respecto a la de la oferta y es utilizado por agentes sociales en
>   contacto con la defensa de los intereses de consumidores y usuarios,
>   como las organizaciones de consumidores. Se expresa en los criterios
>   que usan las personas para adquirir bienes o servicios
>   conscientemente.
>
> El término engloba también un consumo responsable, ético y solidario, > que consiste en consumir con criterios apropiados y racionales…

Summarizing: **consumerismo** refers to the primacy of the consumer with respect to that of the offer. It is used when speaking of the defense of the interests of consumers and users. It is expressed in the criteria employed by people to acquire goods or services in a conscious manner. It includes responsible, ethical consumption, that is, consuming according to proper, rational criteria.

So in many senses, and in its positive connotations, *consumerismo* is directly opposed to *consumerism*, which is a pejorative word.

Note that Spanish also has *[consunción](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AT7bgEa)*, which is another word for *consumption* that refers more to its meaning of debilitating disease (*consumption* was the old term for tuberculosis in English). *Consunción* can simply mean "the action and effect of being consumed", but nowadays it's almost never used like that.

ADDENDA: Realizing I didn't answer about one detail... *Consumo excesivo* is fine (talking about it either as a personal habit, a social custom, or a one-time spree). Just *consumismo* (for the social aspect) is fine as well. *Consumismo excesivo* seems redundant, since *consumismo* by itself already denotes excess. *Consumismo sin control/descontrolado/sin freno/desenfrenado* etc. come to mind in case you want to emphasize the excess (*desenfrenado* ~ "unbridled").

Comment: And Spanish also has *consumición* which refers to *consumption (act of eating/drinking)*

Comment: Great answer.  Since *consumerismo* is a neologism, you might want to be careful to set up a clear context, or define your term, when using this word.